# How to create two alias in elasticsearch, one on hot tier and one on total(or warm, cold) tier?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want define two alias, one on hot tier and one on other tier.
now, I have one alias and when search for data response time is more than one minutes because first search on hot an then warm and cold and ... .
please if you can show me how to do it with example.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using data tiers like hot warm and cold ? Have you define these roles to the nodes ?
As i can see your data is still accessible  which should not be in cold

Comment: Just hot and warm. I want search on hot and return data and don't search on warm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use metadata in your search query. Each document has metadata associated with it, such as the `_index` and `_id` metadata fields. Similarly, it stores `_tier` field.

You can simply add one query in your search context like below:

```json
POST index-alias/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_tier": {
              "value": "data_hot"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "field-name": {
              "value": "search-value"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So here I am also searching on `_tier` field which holds the value `data_hot`.

Check more about [metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-fields.html).